# Install SonataNewsBundle

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-sonata

I learn Symfony 2. I would like have example with SonataAdminBundle. I found:

http://sonata-project.org/bundles/news/2-0/doc/reference/installation.html

but this haven't first point.
i found:

```
[SonataAdminBundle]
    git=http://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Sonata/AdminBundle

[SonataBlockBundle]
    git=http://github.com/sonata-project/SonataBlockBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Sonata/BlockBundle

[SonataCacheBundle]
    git=http://github.com/sonata-project/SonataCacheBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Sonata/CacheBundle

[SonatajQueryBundle]
    git=http://github.com/sonata-project/SonatajQueryBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Sonata/jQueryBundle

[SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle]
    git=http://github.com/sonata-project/SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Sonata/DoctrineORMAdminBundle

[KnpMenuBundle]
    git=http://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Knp/Bundle/MenuBundle

[KnpMenu]
    git=http://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenu.git
    target=/knp/menu

[Exporter]
    git=http://github.com/sonata-project/exporter.git
    target=/exporter

[SonataNewsBundle]
    git=http://github.com/sonata-project/SonataNewsBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Sonata/NewsBundle
```

and run **bin/install vendors.** . Install is correct. Id added line to AppKernel and autoload, and if i run:

```
php app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate SonataNewsBundle
```

i have error:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   Bundle "ApplicationSonataNewsBundle" does not exist or it is not
>   enabled.

So i added:

```
new Application\Sonata\NewsBundle\ApplicationSonataNewsBundle(),
```

and run

```
php app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate SonataNewsBundle
```

then i have error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class
>   'Application\Sonata\NewsBundle\ApplicationSonataNewsBundle' not found
>   in /home/lanox06/Projects/sym2/app/AppKernel.php on line 29

How can i make this? I would like testing these application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move the `./app/Application` folder from `./app` to the `./src` directory.

Answer (score 1):

An other solution is to add the --dest=src option like this :

```
php app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate --dest=src SonataNewsBundle
```